# How to check if computers on a network are running updated windows

Tags: windows, powershell, networking

Sorry if the way the question is phrased is confusing but basically i need a way to check if all the computers are updated on a network because i recently did a service call on a employee's computer and noticed it had not been updated in over a year. Is there a way i can check every computer on the network to if it is updated? My employer uses exclusively windows 7 pro for all employee workstations. Is there a way powershell can be used to automate this task?

Comment: Hi and welcome, 1. What have you tried ? 2. What does it mean for a computer to be "updated", in your words ? Are you looking for specific KBs installed ? Please use the edit button to add details **and code** to your quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something the following:

```
# Import CSV with Workstation HostNames
$RemoteComputers = Import-Csv -Path C:\SomePath\CSVwithHostNames.csv

# Get Last Windows Update Install Date from Remote Computers
# If you don't want to use CSV you can specify like -Computername PC1, PC2, PC3
# You could also pull hostnames from Active Directory and store as variable

#PowerShell 2 or Below
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $RemoteComputers -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering -Property InstalledOn | Sort InstalledOn -Descending | Select InstalledOn, PSComputerName -First 1

#PowerShell 3 or Higher
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $RemoteComputers -ClassName Win32_QuickFixEngineering -Property InstalledOn | Sort InstalledOn -Descending | Select InstalledOn, PSComputerName -First 1
```

Output would look like:

```
InstalledOn           PSComputerName RunspaceId                          
-----------           -------------- ----------                          
7/13/2016 12:00:00 AM SomePCNameHere 691237f3-6ac3-4c7d-a530-5d1717309cfb
```

If using WSUS for updates it would be much better/easier to just run a report to see which workstations are missing updates.

Comment: I guess this needs PowerShell Remoting enabled on the targets ?

Comment: Yes that is correct this would require PowerShell remoting to be enabled. Ill edit my answer above to remove the need for PowerShell Remoting to be enabled on hosts.